# want to move the extra images section below the main image in all product pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, buy-now

I am building an ecommerce website named "bookslab.in". I want to move the extra images of product down below the main image of the product. I am attaching the screenshot of where i want to move the extra images. Any help will be appreciated. I want to move the images below the main big image.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: what's going to be the difference between 'Buy Now' and 'Add to Cart'?

Comment: ADD TO CART button is used to add the products in the cart to buy later on & BUY NOW button is used to buy the products directly going on the checkout page without adding the products in the shopping cart

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its purely css related Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add below css in your css file

add this line in this css file
`http://www.bookslab.in/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css`

```
.more-views {
   clear: both;
}
.product-image, .no-touch .product-img-box .product-image:hover:not(.zoom-available){
      display: initial;
}
```

Other than this you have to check your css for other block

Comment: Okzz i will update u

Comment: Cool @Murtuza it works for me, but how to fix the white space to right side of the main image after moving the small images down, which was acquired by small images

Comment: @SalmanDalal check updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Murtuza again. Is it possible to align the main image with the name of the book which is to the right of the main image in blue. Want to align from top. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add buy now button.

```
<button onclick="buyNow();return false;" id="buy_now">Buy Now</button>
```

And then add ajax code.

```
<script>
    var addToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form', true);
    function buyNow(){
        if (addToCartForm.validator.validate()){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action'),
                type:'POST',
                data:jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize()+'&isAjax=1',
                success:function(){
                    window.location.href='/checkout/onepage/';
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

I see on your website you already moved product images.

**UPDATE**

You need to add above code in

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

where `rwd` is package name and `default` is theme name.

Comment: I updated my answer. No need to add hidden input.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In which program i have to add this function & button. Can you tell me the program name & in which section of the program to add above code.

Comment: You need to add it in the phtml file from where Add to Cart button is coming

Comment: Can you suggest me the program name

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Okzz i will check & get back to you

Comment: Its not working & also i had updated my question